# git refuses to send credentials over HTTP

Tags: authentication, git, curl, credentials, http-basic-authentication

`curl` seems to work fine, but `git` does not. `git` asks for a password, but then doesn't send any credentials.

Works: `curl --netrc http://test.git.unsw.edu.au/` and `curl -u username:password http://test.git.unsw.edu.au/`

Doesn't work: `git remote update`

```
Password for 'http://username@test.git.unsw.edu.au': 
* Couldn't find host test.git.unsw.edu.au in the .netrc file; using defaults
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Host: test.git.unsw.edu.au
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache
```

Why isn't `git` sending credentials?

From an strace, I see:

1. Read `.netrc`
2. `GET /repo/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1` - no credentials
3. `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`
4. Read `.netrc`
5. `GET /repo/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.0` - no credentials
6. `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`
7. Prompt for password
8. Read `.netrc`
9. `* Couldn't find host test.git.unsw.edu.au in the .netrc file; using defaults`
10. `GET /repo/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1` - no credentials
11. `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: I see this too. `curl -n …` works: sends `Authorization: Basic …` on the first try (does not even need a 401 first). But `git push … master` does not send authorization, and when given a 401 and the user enters a password, still does not send authorization. (Git 1.8.1.2 on Linux, connecting to a port on localhost for testing)

Comment: does your server support `Negotiate` instead of just `Basic`?

Comment: I am trying to _write_ the server. First I wanted to use `nc -l -p 8000` or similar to see how Git would send credentials (with the remote being defined as `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://bob:secret@localhost:8080/` etc.), but it sent nothing, and I have not managed to convince it to send anything.

Comment: I would recommend you use `socat` or `stunnel` to decrypt an https connection to `github`, then use `wireshark` to monitor what `git` is doing.

Comment: with the 401 response, what are you sending in the `WWW-Authenticate` header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git seems to only use `CURLAUTH_ANY` which does not work with my particular web server. My web server supports `Negotiate` and `Basic`, so Git does not fallback to `Basic` when `Negotiate` is not available on the client.

Further, there seems to be no option to Git to use anything other than `CURLAUTH_ANY`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manpage, it seems git doesn't take the username option when used with http. But if you put it in your .netrc file, curl should use it. The format for .netrc is

```
machine hostname login yourusername password yourpassword
```

Comment: As I said, `curl --netrc http://test.git.unsw.edu.au/` works.  This is because I have my `.netrc` setup and I have tested with curl that the `.netrc` works correctly.  I agree git doesn't take the username option when used with http, but as you may note, I have not used the username option and the username is set in the url.

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly and missed that.

Comment: I'm very confused that it claims not to find the machine in .netrc... is it being run as a different user? Can you truss it and see which file it actually looks for?

Comment: strace shows it successfully reading `.netrc` 3 times.  I've even tried adding a `default` entry.  It reads `.netrc`, contacts the server and gets a `401`, reads `.netrc`, gets another `401`, prompts for a password, reads `.netrc`, complains about `.netrc`, and gets another `401`.